# Is it possible to upload Bokeh plots to wordpress.com site?

Tags: python, wordpress, bokeh

I want to start doing data visualisation with Bokeh and upload it to my wordpress, and so I generated some html like so

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure,output_file,save
from bokeh.embed import file_html
output_file("line.html")

p=figure(plot_width=400,plot_height=400)

p.circle([1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,2,5,4],size=20,color='navy',alpha=0.5)

save(p)
```

I then attempted to embed the plot by pasting the saved html into wordpress.com's "HTML" tab when making a new post, and it simply erases it.

This same method works perfectly on blogger.

Is there any way to get past this for wordpress?

Thanks!

Comment: According to the WP docs it is possible to use JS in posts, but requires "a few additional steps": https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

Comment: @bigreddot I think that only applies to self-hosted sites, it requires you to access header.php which I dont think is available on wordpress.com

Comment: Ah. I think there may not be any way to do it: https://en.support.wordpress.com/code/#javascript *"Users are not allowed to post JavaScript on WordPress.com blogs."*

Answer (score 0):

You might try the EmbedIt plugin: http://www.matteoionescu.com/wordpress/embed-html/. Just copy the entirety of your Bokeh-generated html file to a "snippet", and embed the snippet in your wordpress post.

I got it to work on my service-hosted wordpress site (not wordpress.com). The plot and tools work fine, but the left edge of the plot always appears in the center of the page (so the plot itself is not centered).

Worth a shot, but as Big red said, javascript might not be allowed at all.